# Grandnode Vendor Concept

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I am trying to understand how the Vendors work on GrandNode. Can we provide them a login account and can they themselves upload products and fulfill the Orders? If yes, can someone point me to how to create the Vendor and how they can login to upload their products.

Thanks

Comment: It's not a official documentation of GrandNode.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood this now.  A vendor can sell the products himself on the portal. We just need to create the Vendor, Create the Customer / Login account for the Vendor and they can upload the products logging into their Account. While I was creating the Account, though I was mentioning the role as Vendor, it was not taking in initial attempt. I need to go back to the customer, edit and assign Vendor role again. Then I am able to login as Vendor and able to upload products.

Answer (score 0):

The Vendor concept in GrandNode is very simple. Vendors = users that has limited access to administration section. Vendor can be named as a Seller. Vendor account can be created directly via administration panel by admin or registered users can submit the "Apply for a vendor account" form, which has to be approved by store owner. If you create account manually, you have to assign them to Vendors customer role on Customer edit page and assign Vendors account to customer account.

Vendor has limited permissions. By default it has access to his products, orders, shipments, vendor reviews and files. Vendors/Sellers can create products and publish them in your store.

In GrandNode, you can also specify the Commission for Vendors. So if somebody makes an order in your store, by default customer will pay to your account and then you have to settle accounts with sellers manually. With commission feature, you can combine it with payment plugin and payout commission automatically.